# Hide softkeyboard on which is inside a fragment from main Activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, hide, fragment, android-softkeyboard

I have a viewpager with few fragments inside it. inside a fragment there are textboxes,so when a user touches a textbox soft keyboard is acitivated (obvious). but i need to hide it when pager is swiped, since pager is in FragmentActivity , even i can get textbox.getWindowToken() i cant pass it to main activity(which is the fragmentActivity) to the viewpager.
appreciate suggestion to hide softkeyboard   on swipe, which generated on top of a fragment

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

am also having same issue , i have solved it , may be it will use full to you try it,

am seeting onfocus changed event listner

```
text_box.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
      // hide soft keypad
    }else {

    }
   }
});
```

then when am swiping fragments softkey board hide for me...